# Reactively call a js function/event with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm new to meteor.js. Still getting used to it.
I get how templates update reactively according to the cursor updates on the server, like this:

```
 {{#if waitingforsomething.length}} Something Happened! {{/if}}
```

This is good to display elements on the page, updating lists and content. Now, my question is: what if I want to call some javascript or fire some event when something gets updated reactively? What would be the right way to do it with meteor.js?

Comment: Do you know [`Tracker.autorun`](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything inside [`Tracker.autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) or [template instance `this.autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun) runs with changes in reactive data sources inside these autoruns.

Reactive data sources are `ReactiveVar` instances, db queries, `Session` variables, etc.

```js
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {

  // Let's define some reactive data source
  this.reactive = new ReactiveVar(0);

  // And put it inside this.autorun
  this.autorun(() => console.log(this.reactive.get()));
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  // Now whenever you click we assign new value
  // to our reactive var and this fires
  // our console.log
  'click'(event, template) {
    let inc = template.reactive.get() + 1;
    template.reactive.set(inc);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit outdated, but [Sacha Greif's *Reactivity Basics*](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/) is a very quick and concise introduction to meteor's reactivity model.

Basically, you have what's called `reactive computations`, code that observes special data objects (`sessions`, `subscriptions`, `cursors`, etc.) and gets executed whenever any of these `reactive sources` changes.

This is exposed via the [Tracker API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Computation works pretty well for me:

```
  Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
        this.computation = Deps.autorun(function () {
            if (something) {
                $(".reactive").html("Something Happened!");
            }
         });
    });

Template.myTemplate.destroyed = function(){
    if (this.computation){
        this.computation.stop()
    }
};
```

I Hope this helps.